# Hair particle system possibly bugging out

Tags: particles, hair

I've been working on body hair for a character in Blender, when it is not rendered , the hair looks fine even during animation, but when rendering it does this weird glitch and i have no idea how to fix it.

[image: non rendered]
[image: rendered]

Anyone have any clue what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it appears I had the amount of hair on render set to 100 and 3 on the viewport and did not notice it.